# How to render HTML in string with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have the following javascript code:

```
var html =  '<div class="col-lg-4 col-references" idreference="'+response+'"><span class="optionsRefer"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove delRefer" style="color:red; cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDel"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil editRefer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRefer" style="cursor:pointer;"></i></span><div id="contentRefer'+response+'">'+refer_summary+'</div><span id="nameRefer'+response+'">'+refer_name+'</span></div>';
$("#references").append(html);
```

When this code runs, the `refer_summary` variable actually contains a string which may contain HTML tags such as `<b>`, `<i>` etc., however, those tags are displayed on the page instead of rendering their behavior.

For example, on the page it would show `<b>` rather actually making the content bold.

How can I go about rendering the HTML tags when the value is appended?

In my Django template I use `{% autoescape off %}{{content}}{% endautoescape %}` so when I first load the page, the content is rendered correctly with bold etc. But how can I do the same thing when appending the html from javascript?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like an XSS attack waiting to happen.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can render HTML using **document.write()**

```
document.write('<html><body><h2>HTML</h2></body></html>');
```

But to append existing HTML string, you need to get the id of the node/tag under which you want to insert your HTML string.

There are two ways by which you can possibly achieve this:

1. Using DOM -

```js
var tag_id = document.getElementById('tagid');
var newNode = document.createElement('p');
newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode('html string'));
```

2. Using innerHTML -

```js
var tag_id = document.getElementById('tagid');
tag_id.innerHTML = 'HTML string';
```

Comment: The advantage of 2 is that no new element/dom as with `write` and 1 is created. Seems like a pure solution.

Comment: It should be added for clarity that in 1 and 2, any HTML markup contained in the `'html string'` will in fact be **parsed** and **converted to DOM** nodes. So this **is** a way for growing the DOM, not just for inserting text strings.

Answer (score 9):

Use $.parseHTML before the append html like as

```
var html =  '<div class="col-lg-4 col-references" idreference="'+response+'"><span class="optionsRefer"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove delRefer" style="color:red; cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDel"></i><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil editRefer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRefer" style="cursor:pointer;"></i></span><div id="contentRefer'+response+'">'+refer_summary+'</div><span id="nameRefer'+response+'">'+refer_name+'</span></div>';
html = $.parseHTML( html);
$("#references").append(html);
```

Comment: The other approaches not worked for me in Outsystems, but this was perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Javascript's `document.createRange().createContextualFragment`:

```
const frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment('<div>One</div><div>Two</div>');
console.log(frag);

/*
  #document-fragment
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
*/
```

https://davidwalsh.name/convert-html-stings-dom-nodes

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in ReactJS, you can use "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" attribute, instead of "innerHTML" attribute.

As it allows the attackers to inject codes (XSS), it is named dangerous!

```
const myHtmlData = `
    <ul>
        <li>Item1<li>
        <li>Item2<li>
    </ul>`;
...
<div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: myHtmlData
}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a particular div an id and then process/change UI in the specific div accordingly.

Given [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp) is an excellent explanation.