# How to print table text to md table using showdown.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, showdown

I'd like to print md table by using showdown.js. But, it doesn't seem to convert to markdown table correctly as I expected.

I tried setting options('table option') to be changed 'true' and converting text to md. but, doesn't work.

Below is the functions I implemented, for your information.

`setMdConvert()` <= As I said, I just tried all options for true.

`getTechDescriptionMd()` <= A test function for converting arbitary markdown text to markdown table

```js
function setMdConvert() {
    var mdConverter = new showdown.Converter();
    var options = showdown.getOptions();
    var keys = Object.keys(options);

    keys.forEach((key) => {
        if(options[key].constructor === boolConstructor)
            mdConverter.setOption(key, true);
    });

    console.log(mdConverter.getOptions());

    return mdConverter;
}

function getTechDescriptionMd() {
    var text = '| h1    |    h2   |      h3 |' +
               '|:------|:-------:|--------:|' +
               '| 100   | [a][1]  | ![b][2] |' +
               '| *foo* | **bar** | ~~baz~~ |';
    var html = mdConverter.makeHtml(text);

    $('.desc-viewer').html(html);
}
```

result:

```
| h1 | h2 | h3 ||:------|:-------:|--------:|| 100 | [a][1] | ![b][2] || foo | bar | baz |
```

Is there any other option that I miss?

Comment: Does it help to insert linebreaks after the final "|" characters of your text variable? ('| h1 | h2 | h3 |\n' + ... )?

Comment: I tried it! But, fail... ;-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modified version of `.getTechDescriptionMd()` that works for me. I added the linebreaks that I already mentioned in my comment from yesterday, plus I initialized `mdConverter` and set its option 'tables' to true (inspired by the [documentation](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/wiki/Showdown-options)).

It looks like this now:

```
function getTechDescriptionMd() {
    var text = '| h1    |    h2   |      h3 |\n' +
               '|:------|:-------:|--------:|\n' +
               '| 100   | [a][1]  | ![b][2] |\n' +
               '| *foo* | **bar** | ~~baz~~ |';

    var mdConverter = new showdown.Converter();
    mdConverter.setOption('tables', true);
    var html = mdConverter.makeHtml(text);
    $('.desc-viewer').html(html);
}
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:left;">h1</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">h2</th>
<th style="text-align:right;">h3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left;">100</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">[a][1]</td>
<td style="text-align:right;">![b][2]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left;"><em>foo</em></td>
<td style="text-align:center;"><strong>bar</strong></td>
<td style="text-align:right;">~~baz~~</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In the example above you need no replacement of escape sequences. But the table markdown needs to have linebreaks in order for the mdConverter to understand that it is dealing with a table. In addition, you need to call `mdConverter.setOption('tables', true)`. 
Or did I misunderstand the nature of your problem with escape sequences?

Comment: Oh :) Thank you!

Comment: how can you see the table and not the (parsed) table tags?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41843921/1705829) it is, document.write()