# how to write html tags inside a react object

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a multi-language website so am using objects and arrays to achieve that however, I want to add span tags inside the react objects. I tried backticks but it's not working

```
let content = {
    english:{
        title:"Welcome to G-tech",
        text:'is an Electronics repair shop specializing in Computer, Phone, and Tablet repairs.',
        button:"mail-in"
    },
    francais:{
        title: 'Welcome to G-tech',
        text:'Il s'agit d'un atelier de réparation d'appareils électroniques spécialisé dans la réparation d'ordinateurs, de téléphones et de tablettes. ',
        button:"mail-in"
    },
    arab:{
        title: 'g-tech مرحبا بكم في ',
        text:'هو خدمة لتصليح الهواتف والحواسيب '
        button:"mail-in"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code to go with your data?  What have you tried?  Where do you want these spans?

Comment: a backtick `\`` is not the same as a single quote `'` you could, of course, use double quotes `"` around text containing single quotes/apostrophes `'`

Comment: I assume multi-language website is in the sense localization. In that case, you can try https://www.i18next.com/

Comment: Are you looking for React's [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to prevent the tags from being escaped during render?

Comment: @James for example in here  english:{
        title:"Welcome to <span className='highlight'>G-tech</span>",
 
    },

Comment: @rayhatfield I think so !!

Comment: Don't forget to use dompurify to sanitize the DOM before to put it in dangerouslySetInnerHTML field. Also, tere is existing solutions like react-i18next to build a multi-lang website.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843654/how-to-render-html-in-string-with-javascript this might help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add tags without any `backticks` or any other thing. In react, You can save `JSX Elements` as if they are string, numbers, e.t.c. Because JSX elements are a part of react applications.
So I guess it's not really hard to add to add `span` tag to your text property.

```
function MultiLingualParagraphs() {
  const [multiLingualData, setMultiLingualData] = useState([
    {
      language: "English",
      title: "Welcome to G-tech",
      text: (
        <span>
          is an <strong>Electronics</strong> repair shop specializing in
          Computer, Phone, and Tablet repairs.
        </span>
      ),
      button: "mail-in"
    },
    {
      language: "francais",
      title: "Welcome to G-tech",
      text: (
        <span>
          Il s'agit d'un <strong>atelier</strong> de réparation d'appareils
          électroniques spécialisé dans la réparation d'ordinateurs, de
          téléphones et de tablettes.
        </span>
      ),
      button: "mail-in"
    },
    {
      language: "Arabic",
      title: "g-tech مرحبا بكم في ",
      text: (
        <span>
          هو خدمة لتصليح الهواتف والحوا<strong>سيب</strong>
        </span>
      ),
      button: "mail-in"
    }
  ]);

  return multiLingualData.map((v, i) => (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{v.language}</h2>
      <hr />
      <h4>{v.title}</h4>
      <p>{v.text}</p>
      <button>{v.button}</button>
      <hr />
    </div>
  ));
}
```

You can see working demo of this on this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-fire-kuygx?file=/src/App.js:73-1203).


To learn more about JSX Elements and [Babel Compiler](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react). Check this [link](https://www.codecademy.com/article/react-setup-ii#:%7E:text=Babel%20is%20a%20JavaScript%20compiler,compile%20JSX%20into%20regular%20JavaScript.&text=You%27re%20going%20to%20install,save%2Ddev%20babel%2Dcore%20.).